# Php preg_match code for match the phone number

Tags: php, preg-match

`preg_match()` is not working in `+(91) 111 11111`

The code is:

```
$number = +91 111 11111;

if (preg_match('/^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[(]\+[)]?([-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*)?((\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{2,4})(?:[-.x ]*(\d+))?)\s*$/', $number)) {
   echo "True"; 
}
```

It is working. But not working in `+91 (111) 11111`

Comment: Are you trying to lex it? Seems like you're telling that the `$number` shouldn't be string and that's why you got `\s*` as start there (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You may want to revisit your `regex` or try something like this:

```
<?php

    if (preg_match('#(^[\+\d][\d]{1,2})?(\()?([\d\s]*)?(\))?([-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*)?((\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{2,4})(?:[-.x ]*(\d+))?)\s*$#', $number)) {
        echo "True";
    }
```

**UPDATE: CHANGED THE PATTERN**

```
<?php

    // MATCHES: "+91 (111) 11111" OR "+91 111 11111" OR "91 (101) 23454" 
    // OR "+(91) (101) 23454" 
    // BUT NOT "1234500000000000000000000" OR "+121(121)38778" 
    $rx     = '#(^[\+\d](\()?[\d]{1,2})*(\))?(\s)(\()?([\d\s]*?)(\))?(\s)([\d\s]*?)$#';
    if (preg_match($rx, $number)) {
        //echo "True";
    }
```

Comment: It's working in +(91) 111 11111. But it also works in 1234500000000000000000000. This is not a phone number. I want to check whether it is phone number or not.

Comment: @faziltm  Perhaps you could change regex to: `
 $rx     = '#(^[\+\d][\d]{1,2})*(\s)(\()?([\d\s]*?)(\))?(\s)([\d\s]*?)$#';`